# Ubuntu 19.04 on RTX, messed graphics on live USB

Tags: boot, usb, 19.04, nvidia-geforce

I downloaded, verified the MD5 digest and fleshed ubuntu 19.04 into an USB flash drive using ubuntu 18.04's usb creator and windows's rufus and both gave me this result:

[image]

My monitor's resolution is 2550 x 1440, connected through a displayport to a RTX 2070. This appears right after selecting either "try ubuntu without installing" or "install ubuntu". I just repeated everything I did when installed 18.04, which worked just fine. Can anyone help me? What am I missing?

Comment: You probably need `nomodeset` as a boot parameter.

Comment: What happens if you plug the monitor into the motherboard's onboard graphics? I'd imagine that would at least let you install it and maybe this will go away after you get the drivers installed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia that was it!